# Unir varias paginas en un solo Array

Tags: php, array, bucles

Hola Necesito leer 17 direcciones de URL para unificar en una sola lista tengo la logica pero no me resulta solo me imprime la ultima linea. Me dan una mano para corregir que me imprima todas las linea.
Gracias

```
$sat_file=array();
        for ($x = 1; $x <= 17; $x++) {
            $sat_file[]='http://69.64.55.115/bin'.$x.'.txt';                
                foreach ($sat_file as $url_final) {         
                        $ch = curl_init($url_final);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                        $result = curl_exec($ch);
                        curl_close($ch);
                }
                echo $result;
```

Comment: Mete el `echo $result;` en el `foreach()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En cada pasada del for estas re-asignando el valor del array, tienes que:

1. indexar el array con el $x del for

   ```
    $sat_file=array();
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 17; $x++) {
        $sat_file[$x]='http://69.64.55.115/bin'.$x.'.txt';     
    }         

    echo json_encode($sat_file);
   ```

o

2. utilizar el array_push para insertar el valor en el array.

   ```
   <?php
   $pila = array("naranja", "plátano");
   array_push($pila, "manzana", "arándano");
   print_r($pila);
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion, me quede con la 1era opcion me trabajo de inmediato.